# 2 ProxyPass SSL wildcard on HTTPD2

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, https, proxypass

So basically I am trying to setup 3 different SSL virtualhosts. I have the following setup

beta.website.com

api-beta.website.com

app-beta.website.com

beta is our old platform, api and app our part of our new platform and they live on port 8000 (node api) and 3000 (node app). So if I go to go to the sites via http with the port numbers everything works fine. However I am trying to setup proxy pass and I am so close to having it all work.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api-beta.website.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/website.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/website.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.crt
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_api_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_api_log
    LogLevel warn
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName app-beta.website.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/website.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/website.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.crt
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_app_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_app_log
    LogLevel warn
  </VirtualHost>
```

Beyond that I have the virtualhost for the main beta.website.com but it is a little long to post here and I don't think it is the problem. So currently here is what happens

https://beta.website.com Works, directs to the correct spot and has SSL

https://api-beta.website.com Works, directs to the correct spot and has SSL

https://app-beta.website.com Almost works, directs to api-beta.website.com content, but has the correct URL and SSL.

Basically I am trying to proxy pass content from :3000 to app-beta.website.com but it is showing me the content from :8000. I have tried manually going to :3000 and :8000 and they both work as expected and show the correct content under http. Any ideas on what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who needs to deal with this. The issue (as far as I can tell) was that my higher port number (8000) came before my lower port number (3000). Switching the virtual hosts order in my ssl config and restarting apache fixed the issue. Someone with more knowledge please let me know WHY.